# Enable NOPASSWD without manual interaction

Tags: sudo

I need to enable NOPASSWD for one user across 60+ hosts. I've only ever enabled it manually, using `visudo`. Is there a way to script this? I can easily log into all hosts as root, but I'm not sure if there is a command I can run to automatically add someone to the sudoers file with the NOPASSWD flag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a file with the required `NOPASSWD` line and drop it into `/etc/sudoers.d`. To verify the correctness of the file, use `visudo` to create it:

```
visudo -f some-file
cp some-file /etc/sudoers.d/
```

Then use `scp` or whatever means of control you use to send the files to the target systems.

`sudoers.d` files are read in lexicographic order, so use some numbering like `00-something`, `99-most-important`, etc. (like in `/etc/grub.d/`) to make ordering easier.

Comment: This is perfect, happy to accept when I'm allowed. Any idea what I could do if the user already exists in `/etc/sudoers` without the NOPASSWD flag (which causes them to be prompted because they have two rules, one which does not have NOPASSWD)?

Comment: Ugh, looks like I may have to use nasty hacks or just manually remove the incorrect line, as it was appended to the file *after* sudoers.d is loaded

Comment: @Hamy the last applicable entry is used by `sudo`, and usually the last entry in `/etc/sudoers` is `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d`, so files in that directory are read after entries in `sudoers`. So the entries in files in `sudoers.d` take precedence over those in `sudoers`.

Comment: Yup. Guess this has become a learning opportunity lol. Lesson is "use external files in sudoers.d when you need to add stuff programmatically"

Comment: @Hamy also note that `sudoers.d` files are read in lexicographic order, so use some numbering like `00-something`, `99-most-important`, etc. (like `/etc/grub.d/`) to make ordering easier.